# How can I implement IEnumerable<T> on a collection that has a MultiDimensional Array inner list?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, multidimensional-array, ienumerable

I have a collection:

```
interface IPinCollection : IEnumerable<IPin>
{
 IPin this[int [,] indices] { get; set; }
}
```

Basically it has an innerlist as matrix which has IPin instance in its each [rowindex,columnIndex].

What I want to achieve is to be able to walkthrough the all IPin instances of this matrix with for..each.

Can you suggest me a thread-safe,simple and quick way to implement IEnumerable to achieve this?

Comment: Look up the yield statement. That combined with nested for loops should get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If your underlying property is an `Array`, you can use [`Array.GetLength(int dimension)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) to get the length of the array in the specified dimension, although in that case you can simply use its built-in enumerator.

This works, for example:

```
int[,] arr = new int[,] 
{ 
   { 1, 2, 3 },    
   { 4, 5, 6 },
   { 7, 8, 9 },
   { 10, 11, 12 } 
};

foreach (int i in arr)
   Console.WriteLine(i);
```

It means you can simply return values from the array, in the order its enumerator returns them:

```
class PinCollection : IPinCollection
{
     private IPin[,] _array;

     #region IEnumerable<int> Members

     public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
     {
         foreach (IPin i in _array)
             yield return i;
     }

     #endregion

     #region IEnumerable Members

     System.Collections.IEnumerator
         System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
         foreach (IPin i in _array)
             yield return i;
     }

     #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is of known dimension, for example `private readonly IPin[,] data;`, then actually pretty simply (since you can already `foreach` over a multi-dimensional array; but note that `T[*,*]` doesn't *itself* implement `IEnumerable<T>` - since that isn't *technically* a requirement for `foreach`):

```
    public IEnumerator<IPin> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (IPin pin in pins) yield return pin;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for documenting that IEnumerable isn't required for a foreach loop. The runtime actually uses duck typing for this :)

Comment: @MattDavey - no, the **compiler** uses duck-typing ;p But actually, in this case it is using `IEnumerable` (non-generic).